# Passing zero count to glUniform4fv: specification vs Emscripten implementation

Tags: language-lawyer, webgl, specifications, emscripten

My application is written in C++ using OpenGL API, and I build it for desktop OS, as well as for web, using Emscripten. Not so long ago a strange bug emerged: everything works okay on desktop (with any optimizations, valgrind-clean), but crashes in WebGL with the following error:

> exception thrown: TypeError: Argument 2 of
> WebGLRenderingContext.uniform4fv could not be converted to any of:
> Float32Array, UnrestrictedFloatSequence.

I built it with `-g4` (generate readable JS code with debug info) and figured out that sometimes `glUniform4fv` gets zero as it's `count` argument. OpenGL call wrapper generated by Emscripten is the following:

```js
function _glUniform4fv(location, count, value) {
        var view;
        if (4*count <= GL.MINI_TEMP_BUFFER_SIZE) {                                                                                    
                // avoid allocation when uploading few enough uniforms                                                                
                view = GL.miniTempBufferViews[4*count-1];                                                                             
                for (var i = 0; i < 4*count; i += 4) {                                                                                
                        view[i] = HEAPF32[(((value)+(4*i))>>2)];                                                                      
                        view[i+1] = HEAPF32[(((value)+(4*i+4))>>2)];                                                                  
                        view[i+2] = HEAPF32[(((value)+(4*i+8))>>2)];                                                                  
                        view[i+3] = HEAPF32[(((value)+(4*i+12))>>2)];                                                                 
                }                                                                                                                     
        } else {                                                                                                                      
                view = HEAPF32.subarray((value)>>2,(value+count*16)>>2);                                                              
        }                                                                                                                             
        GLctx.uniform4fv(GL.uniforms[location], view);                                                                                
}
```

So when this wrapper gets zero `count` and enters first branch, it executes `view = GL.miniTempBufferViews[-1];`, which is `undefined`. This value goes to `GLctx.uniform4fv`, yielding the above error.

Ok, let's take a look at [OpenGL documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glUniform.xml), ES 2.0 version, which is base for WebGL1:

> *count*
>
> Specifies the number of elements that are to
> be modified. This should be 1 if the targeted
> uniform variable is not an array, and 1 or more if it is
> an array.

> ...

> **Errors**

> ...

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if count is less than 0.

So I can't see anything about what OpenGL should do when `count` is zero. I assumed, that it's a correct value, when we have nothing to pass to a shader. At least, it shouldn't crash.

So I have the following questions:

1. Is it undefined or implementation-defined behavior from the respect of GLES 2.0 specification?
2. What should be Emscripten's correct reaction? It's definitely not allowed to set error state as there is no such error in specs. But maybe it would be more correct to pass zero-sized `Float32Array` to `GLctx.uniform4fv`, letting browser's Webgl implementation to deal with it? Should I report an issue to Emscripten developers?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from an answer here? You ask basically: "Why doesn't Emscripten follow the standard or has a bug?" I highly doubt that anyone besides the Emscripten developers can tell you why they did something.

Comment: it seems to me you should just fix the bug in the emscripten library and submit a pull request. Note that you can easily use your own custom version of the library. Copy `library_gl.js` to your project, compile with `--js-library library_gl.js`  I did that in my project so I could make `gl.shaderSource` modify my OpenGL 3.x shaders to WebGL2.0 shaders

Answer (score 0):

Circling back to this old issue, I believe the this was fixed in emscripten in https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/16837